# Adding multiple event listeners to one link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension and am having some difficulty getting my event listeners to work correctly.

manifset.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "testing this",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function (stuff){
    traverseBookmarks(stuff[0].children[0].children);
  });
});

  function traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
    for(var i=0;i<bookmarkTreeNodes.length;i++) {
      var bookmark = document.createElement('a');

      if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].url){
        console.log("here mother");
        bookmark.href = bookmarkTreeNodes[i].url;
        bookmark.target = "_blank";
      }
      else{
        bookmark.addEventListener("click", addChildren(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children), false);
      }
      bookmark.innerHTML = bookmarkTreeNodes[i].title;
      document.body.appendChild(bookmark);
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

      if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children) {
        traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children);
      }
    }
  }

  function addChildren(children) {
    var windows = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
      window.open(children[i].url);
      // windows += 'window.open(' + children[i].url + ');';
    }
    return windows;
  }
```

The issue I'm running into is every time I click on the extension's icon to open the popup the first link in the event listener gets triggered and it ends up only opening up the first tab.

The goal is to be able to click the folder(now just a link symbolizing the folder) and open all links inside that folder. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bookmark.addEventListener("click", 
                           addChildren(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children), false);
```

**You are executing the function here**

```
addChildren(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children)
           ^                             ^
           |                             |
```

you need to pass in the reference

```
bookmark.addEventListener("click", addChildren, false);
```

Instead you can wrap the handler in a closure and pass in the current value of `i` to the **[IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)** .

```
(function(num) {
    bookmark
     .addEventListener("click", function() {               
                                  addChildren(bookmarkTreeNodes[num].children) })
                               } , false );
})(i);
```

Comment: I think you had a syntax error in your example, thank you. That helped. Now I can open the popup with then event listener. Having a little trouble with opening multiple tabs, but that's another issue that I can work through. Thank you very much! I pasted the code I ended up using which is basically exactly like yours.
 (function(num) {
          bookmark.addEventListener("click", function() {
            addChildren(bookmarkTreeNodes[num].children, false );
          })})(i);